# Why is it an anti-pattern to use presentations instead entities?

Tags: php, symfony, presentation

In a Symfony project using PHP, I am using a design pattern that I don't know how they call it. Some are saying that this is a bad anti-pattern, and I should't use it. Could you tell mewhy is this wrong?

Above the Entity layer I use Presentation objects. This means Entities are only used for managing data in the database, and when I load an Entity, I "convert" it into a presentation object that is used further.

The drawback is I always have to "synchronize" the presentations and entities when I query for data or when I insert or update data. This means constantly calling methods like createEntityFromPresentation($presentation) or createPresentationFromEntity($entity).

The advantage of it that I can bravely monkey around with presentations without having to worry about accidentally persisting/updating data (However this was relevant only when I started to programming with Symfony).
I use the presentation to pass to the view, or to serialize it and send back to an API call.

Could you tell why shouldn't I use this pattern?

Comment: It is an interesting question but not well suited for stackoverflow.  If your skin is reasonably thick then maybe try /reddit/php The answer below has some good points.  It mostly depends on if the extra effort of maintaining another layer is really worth it for your apps.

Comment: there might be good reasons. I wouldn't say it's an anti-pattern per se. However, it's very opinionated...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a style of object I'd call a DTO (Data Transfer Object), or a (similar) VO (Value Object).  A DTO generally just holds data, where a VO will often be checked as it is created - so you might throw an exception if there is something wrong (for example, you'd check the format while making  `$email = new EmailAddressValueObject('this.must@valid.be');`)

When you are sending the entity out in what would be an uncomplicated fashion (to the screen, or an API), I would consider that to be somewhat redundant, although it does have the advantage of only allowing a very specific subset of the information to be sent out. For the output to an API, that can often be done entirely within the serialisation 'groups', which limits what parts of the raw entity is going to be converted to JSON. This can be more flexible than having a number of fixed properties in an object.

For input from a form and then writing to a record, DTOs as a conversion layer can be helpful to disconnect the form inputs from the database record. Sometimes there are extra fields that a form needs, but are only used for validation and other checks before things are written to the database. One form could be collecting data for more than one type of record. As an example, I've got part of a form that converts a two radio buttons into a few different properties, based on the choices made.

It is also very useful as a validation layer - the DTO can be validated so that is has all the right fields and interactions between those fields (including what could end up being multiple entities/records in a database).

In short, it's not bad, but you don't always need it - there can be less involved ways to do some of the simple things. When you are doing something more complex, then the extra level can give a great deal of flexibility.